# Python 3 pow() / ** timing out

Tags: python, python-3.x, exponential, pow

I'm undertaking a problem from Project Euler (#188) and I've run into a wall. The problem's specification is as follows:

[image]
My solution in python is as follows:

```
Q = input()
List1 = []
List2 = []
Answers = []
for i in range(int(Q)):
    List1.append(input())
    List2.append(List1[i].split(" "))
    for j in range(int(List2[i][1])):
        List2[i][0] = int(List2[i][0]) ** int(List2[i][0])
    Answers.append(int(List2[i][0]) % int(List2[i][2]))
for k in range(len(Answers)):
    print(Answers[k])
```

It works perfectly for smaller inputs, but once exponentiation gets very large, the program works for such a long time, that I get a timeout error. Is there any way around the obvious inefficiency of python 3's exponentiation, or am I perhaps doing something else wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use the second argument to `pow`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow

Comment: It isn't *python* inefficiency but algorithmic inefficiency.

Comment: Notice that you're not using moduleo *within* the inner for loop *at all*.

Comment: I'm pretty sure using the built in expmod defeats the point and spirit of the problem. It'd be like asking you to implement a square root approximation and you just used `sqrt`. If you're doing this for a grade, you likely won't get a lot of credit.

Comment: It might not be enough anyway, noticing now that there’s still a loop with up to 10^18 iterations.

Comment: You should re-consider your algorithm. This is a *math problem*. The point of Project Euler is thinking of something *other than a brute force solution*

Comment: Also do not store answers in the variable, because of memory consumption. Just print it.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers involved are just too large. You are trying to brute force the problem, which won't work - some numbers involved may actually take up terabytes of space - or even so much memory that it wouldn't fit in the observable universe. Python can't help you; there is some answer involving smarter math. Try out printing some exponentiation results - for example, the powers of three. Look at the remainders. There will probably be some repetition or pattern. Follow and generalise that.

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice the age of the question. Keeping it here for future askers.